# How are the parts of GPT connected?

Tags: neural-networks

Reading Stephen Wolfram's [explanation](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/) of ChatGPT, it sounds as if first you train a very powerful "autocomplete" function that doesn't know anything specifically about chatbots, and then you create a corpus of chatbot-dialogs on top of that model to show it how to be a chatbot specifically. I'm curious if anyone can explain in a bit more detail how this process works technically, ie taking an already-trained model and "specializing" it with a second training corpus. How are the two neural networks related to one another?

Comment: It's just more training. There's no "end of training process" that stops you from doing any more training after that; you can just keep doing even more training. There's probably some kind of secret sauce in ChatGPT, but this isn't it

Comment: ChatGPT is a decoder-only transformer model. For a full on (hopefully not too technical explanation), please [read this extensive post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/how-does-the-decoder-only-transformer-architecture-work). It also goes into how the transformer is trained (in two stages).

Answer (score 1):

ChatGPT derives also from [InstructGPT](https://openai.com/research/instruction-following) that is subject to a reinforcement learning training with human feedback (called [RLHF](https://openai.com/research/learning-from-human-preferences)) in order to enble it for instruction following.

Basically, to get a chatGPT you take a GPT model, pre-train it to predict the next token in a sentence (so that it learns the structure of the language), and then RLHF is applied to enable it to follow instructions specified in a prompt. Otherwise it will give you just random (but plausible) complexions of sentences.

The power of chatGPT is the combination of a very large model (billions of parameters), a huge dataset, and a large collection of human annotated prompts and results for the instruction follwing thing.