# How are the transformer encoder outputs handled?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, transformer

According to the Attention Is All You Need paper, the transformer's encoder portion is described as

> The encoder is composed of a stack of N = 6 identical layers. Each layer has two
> sub-layers. The first is a multi-head self-attention mechanism, and the second is a simple, position-wise fully connected feed-forward network.

How are the outputs of the N<sub>x</sub>=6 identical layers put together? Is it via concatenation, summation, element-wise product, or are the 6 blocks placed in sequential order, etc? Is the same also done for the decoder?

[image: Transformer architecture]

Comment: See [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/how-does-the-decoder-only-transformer-architecture-work) for an extensive explanation on the decoder. The encoder 'stacking' works the same. They are put in sequence.

Comment: the output of one feeds into the input of the next