How does casual and padding mask work in decoder-only models?
I am trying to implement a decoder-only model from scratch using PyTorch, but I am confused about how the masking works. From what I understand, when we have encoder-decoder architecture, the padding mask is in the encoder and the casual mask is in the decoder. Then, with the decoder-only architecture, do we combine them, and if we do, how will this look?

See https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/how-does-the-decoder-only-transformer-architecture-work/40180#40180 for some more info. Maybe you can get your answer more clearly there.
